# Reading strange xml doc

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read this XML File:

```
<server>
  <Version date="06/05/2013">2.5.4</Version>
  <Lastfix path="\">Now reading basic config files! Read the README file!</Lastfix>
  <Version date="07/05/2013">2.5.3</Version>
  <Lastfix path="\wServer\ClientProcessor.cs">Fixed character creation bugs (related to mysql, download and import the new struct.sql file under db!)</Lastfix>
  <Version date="06/05/2013">2.5.0</Version>
  <Lastfix path="\">BIG stability fix, register fix, buy gold fix</Lastfix>
  <Version date="02/05/2013">2.4.1</Version>
  <Lastfix path="\wServer\realm\entities\player\Player.UseItem.cs">Almost finished dungeon keys!</Lastfix>
  <Version date="30/04/2013">2.3.1</Version>
  <Lastfix path="\wServer\realm\entities\player\Player.UseItem.cs">Dungeon keys now working!</Lastfix>
  <Version date="30/04/2013">2.3.0</Version>
  <Lastfix path="\wServer\realm\entities\player\Player.Chat.cs">Added /who, /tell, /server commands!</Lastfix>
</server>
```

But cannot figure how to get the version and the lastfix text value!

I was trying this code.

```
XmlDocument version = new XmlDocument();
version.Load(path);

foreach (XmlNode node in version.SelectNodes("server"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("lastfix_date").InnerText);
}
```

But no success

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the XML here. Expecting people to leave this site to even determine what you're asking, and then come back here to answer it, isn't how StackOverflow works. Also, if the majority of your question is somewhere else, and that other site is not available, your question becomes meaningless. It also can't be used in searches that would benefit future readers here. The [help] pages have more details about how to ask questions here, as well as some tips on asking them in a way that will help you get answers. Thanks.

Comment: How should I include XML tags? thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you can't figure out how to get each pair version and lastfix. Or a particular pair? Or you didn't bother reading up on .net and Xml.

Comment: What output format/objects do you want?

Comment: The output should be the numbers on Version tag and the lastfix text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
XmlDocument version = new XmlDocument();
version.Load(path);

foreach (XmlNode node in version.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes)
{
    if (node.Name == "Version")
        MessageBox.Show("Version: " + node.InnerText);
    else if (node.Name == "Lastfix")
        MessageBox.Show("LastFix: " + node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as "correct" as an xmlpath solution, but I love to use linq `Aggregate()` whenever I can, so I present my humble solution:

```
void Main()
{
  XmlDocument v = new XmlDocument();
  v.LoadXml(@"<server>
<Version date=""06/05/2013"">2.5.4</Version>
<Lastfix path=""\"">Now reading basic config files! Read the README file!</Lastfix>
<Version date=""07/05/2013"">2.5.3</Version>
<Lastfix path=""\wServer\ClientProcessor.cs"">Fixed character creation bugs (related to mysql, download and import the new struct.sql file under db!)</Lastfix>
<Version date=""06/05/2013"">2.5.0</Version>
<Lastfix path=""\"">BIG stability fix, register fix, buy gold fix</Lastfix>
<Version date=""02/05/2013"">2.4.1</Version>
<Lastfix path=""\wServer\realm\entities\player\Player.UseItem.cs"">Almost finished dungeon keys!</Lastfix>
<Version date=""30/04/2013"">2.3.1</Version>
<Lastfix path=""\wServer\realm\entities\player\Player.UseItem.cs"">Dungeon keys now working!</Lastfix>
<Version date=""30/04/2013"">2.3.0</Version>
<Lastfix path=""\wServer\realm\entities\player\Player.Chat.cs"">Added /who, /tell, /server commands!</Lastfix>
</server>");

  var result = v.SelectSingleNode("server").ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>().Aggregate(
     new List<item>(),
     (list, node) => {
      if (node.Name == "Version")
      {
        list.Add(new item { versionD = node.Attributes["date"].Value, versionN = node.InnerText, lastfix = "" });
        return list;
      }
      else
      {
        list.Last().lastfix = node.InnerText;
        return list;
      }
    });

  result.Dump();
}

public class item {
  public string versionD { get; set; }
  public string versionN { get; set; }
  public string lastfix { get; set; }
}
```

returns

[image: result]

When run in linqPad (at linqPad.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Linq based solution (you are using XmlDocument, however don't specify that you must)

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\myServerFile.xml");
List<string> serverVersions = new List<string>();
foreach (var element in xDoc.Elements("server").Elements("Version"))
{
       string version = (string)element + " " + (string)((XElement)element.NextNode);
       serverVersions.Add(version);
}
```

You can then do whatever you wish with the "serverVersions" list of strings

Comment: I get repeated items while doing a foreach to the <list>